# Why does my email encryption certificate need to be signed?

Tags: cryptography, email, account-security

My email client allows for separate keys for signing and encryption, so my signature key pair can be generated and signed by a third party and my encryption keys can be generated by me personally without 3rd party involvement, or so I thought.

So why does my public encryption key need to be signed? I just use it for encryption, not identification.

Comment: In PKI public key is used to encrypt and private key is used to decrypt. That is, anyone can encrypt for you using your public key, but only you can decrypt using your private key. So to send encrypted email to someone you need to have their public key. However, you don't have a way to know that Alice's public key really comes from Alice or it is Mallory impersonating Alice. As such, you need to confirm identity by the outside means. One way is to trust a CA. Other way is in-person exchange. In both of these cases such public key is signed (CA or yourself) as a way to indicate trust.

Comment: Good point - I hadn't considered that I might need to prove that the key is from me!

Comment: @bukko In general public keys for encryption or signing need to be *trusted* before they can be used. Keep this in mind as a good rule-of-thumb (obviously ephemeral DH public keys used in DH key agreement do not immediately need trust).